# Difference between Page layout vs Layout page and Which is correct method to add a page : Pagelayout or Webpart page then webpart in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

What is difference between Page layout and Layout page?

Which is correct method to add a page : Pagelayout or Webpart page then webpart in Sharepoint 2010

Please, Guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page Layouts are predefined layouts in SharePoint based which you can create end user pages, called `Content Page`. The advantage of Page layout is that you control the layout and the content type at the central location.

It is analogous to OOP concepts. Think of page layouts as classes and content pages as objects, which the end user sees.

The webpart page is a unique in itself that it is not associated with page layout. It is a complete page in itself. This way, you can completely customize a webpart page using SharePoint Designer.

Note that, Page Layouts are only available in Publishing Site template in SharePoint.

If you want to create a page and are working on publishing site, prefer to create a page, based on a pre-created layout, else create a webpart page on non-publishing site.